# Wait until Worksheet.Calculate has finished

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

Can I force saving

> myWorkbook.SaveAs

to wait until

> myWorksheet.Calculate()

has finished to recalculate all the formulas?
there is an event called

> myWorksheet1.OnCalculate

but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Use `DoEvents` before the `SaveAs`?

Comment: thank you but i can't find this function !

Comment: How have you defined your Excel Application?

Comment: var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var myWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

Comment: Try `app.DoEvents();` if this doesn't work then I will have to test it...

Comment: NO there is no function with this name on app , but there is the event (Oncalculate) I'm pretty sure that it's the solution but I don't know how to use an event ....

Comment: While I am still creating a sample.. what happens if you use this `Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: Like I already told you , there is no Function with this name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37954/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1863359)